# How to read a variable from a java class in jess?

Tags: java, jess

I'm trying to read two variables from a `Java` class into my `.clp` file to compare.

Can anyone please help me with this. Thank you.

I'm trying in this way..

```
(deftemplate Alarm  (declare (from-class Alarm)))

(Alarm (measuredValue ?m) (nominalValue ?n))

(printout t ?m ?n crlf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an fact of class `Alarm` inserted in working memory. Then a rule like this

```
(defrule compalarm
  ?alarm <- (Alarm (measuredValue ?m)(nominalValue ?n))
=>
  (printout t ?m " - " $n crlf)
)
```

lets you access the fields of some such `Alarm` object. As to comparing those values: you can do this in the rule, but you didn't write how, so I didn't add anything.

**Later** To use a Java class for creating an object and insert it as a fact:

```
(bind ?alarm (new pack.age.Alarm))
(set-member ?alarm measuredValue 42)
(set-member ?alarm nominalValue 50)
(add ?alarm)
```

You can use `(get-member ...)` to access fields in a Java object.

See the Jess manual for this (and more) information.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have created an Alarm class in java where I am receiving two values (measured and nominal). I have implemented a .clp file and calling this .clp to Jess engine. before going to write any rule I want to read those value to that .clp file to check... can you please give me any idea for this? How could I create fact of a java class? Looking forward to hear you. Thanks in advance.